# Sorted insert using Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, iteration

I have some difficulties to implement one iterative function for sorted insert in linked list. I have previously done that with recursion which is much easier when the `insert()` function is called, but here I am a bit confused with how to implement the `(l->data < data)` condition:

```
typedef struct E_Type * List;

struct E_Type
{
  int data;
  struct E_Type* next;
};
```

and the function:

```
insert(List & l, int data){
  if (l == 0 || l->data > data){
    List new_list = new E_Type;
    new_list->data = data;
    new_list->next = l;
    l = new_list;
  }
  else if (l->data < data){
    List new_list = new E_Type; 
    new_list->data = data;
    new_list->next = l; //i am shooting in the dark with this one
    l = new_list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I won't code this up for you, but will offer some hints.

Fundamentally, there are two cases:

1. The element being inserted becomes the new head. In this case, you need to update `l`.
2. The element being inserted does **not** become the new head. In this case you need a loop.

If I were you, I'd work through both cases using pen and paper first.

Comment: Or go with the clever implementation and use a dummy head which greatly simplifies the code.